# Output unique categories

Tags: gwcode-categories

I am outputting a list of categories for entries which have prices using the code below, how can I filter it to only show unique categories? Right now it is showing multiple categories with the same name.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="off"}
{if price}
        {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear"}{if depth == 2}{cat_url_title}{/if}{/exp:gwcode_categories}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a way using Stash and unique filter.

```
 {exp:stash:set_list name="products" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name"}
        {if price}
            {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" depth="2"}
            {stash:parent_item_title}{parent_url_title}{/stash:parent_item_title}
            {stash:item_name}{cat_name}{/stash:item_name}
            {stash:item_url}{cat_url_title}{/stash:item_url}
            {/exp:gwcode_categories}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

    <form>
        <select><option value="">Step 2. Select Option</option>
            {exp:stash:get_list name="products" unique="yes" orderby="item_name" sort="asc"}
            <option class="{parent_item_title}" value="{item_url}">{item_name}</option>
            {/exp:stash:get_list} 
        </select>
    </form>
```